# elasticsearch vs hbase/hadoop for realtime statistics

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hbase, hdfs, bigdata

I'm loggin millions of small log documents weekly to do:

- ad hoc queries for data mining
- joining, comparing, filtering and calculating values
- many many fulltext-search with python
- run this operations with all millions of docs, some times every day

My first thought was put all docs in HBase/HDFS and run Hadoop jobs generating stats results.

The problem is: some of results must be near real-time.

So, after some research I discovered ElasticSearch and Now I'm thinking about transfer all millions of documents and use DSL-Queries to generate stats results.

Is this a good idea? ElasticSearch seems to be so easy to handle with millions/billions of documents.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- For real-time search Analytics Elastic Search is a good choice.
- Definitely easier to setup and handle than Hadoop/HBase/HDFS.
- Elastic-Search vs HBase Good Comparison: http://db-engines.com/en/system/Elasticsearch%3BHBase